# Как в Spring 3 задавать при сериализации в JSON другой Content-Type, либо отлавливать любой ответ с сервера на клиенте в ExtJS?

Tags: spring, javascript, java, extjs

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с такой задачей:
     Использую в разработке `Ext Js 3.1` и `Spring 3`. Используя функцию

```
fp.getForm().submit({
    url: 's3/uploadform.form',
    waitMsg: 'Загрузка файла...',
    success: function(fp, o){
        msg('Success', 'Загрузка завершена');
    }
});
```

Ext JS отправляет данные на сервер, где происходят нужные операции, и клиент ждет от сервера ответ

```
{success:true}
```

В `Spring 3` есть удобная вещь, которая автоматически сериализует возвращаемые объекты в `JSON` при помощи библиотеки `jackson`. Для удобства, я создал объект со всеми нужными полями плюс поле `boolean success`. Он прекрасно срабатывает, и отправляет назад клиенту

```
{"success":true, "anyField":"anyString"}
```

При этом используется подобная функция:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadform.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
TransactionResultMessage uploadForm(@Valid ImportXfd xfd, 
                                    BindingResult validationResults) {
    /*
     Тут все что надо и возвращение моего объекта
     TransactionResultMessage 
    */
}
```

И `Ext JS` не хочет принимать это.
В консоли ошибок `JavaScript` браузера, выводится

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json.
```

Такое выводится в `google chrome`. Mozilla вообще с какого-то этапа стала предлагать сохранить пришедший ответ с сервера на диске. Тут, как я начал понимать, ExtJs ругается на то, что приходит тип `application/json`. Но этот MIME тип генерирует Spring, и у меня, логически, нет доступа к этому. Так вот новый вопрос:
      *Как* мне сделать `Content-type`, отправляемый с сервера, типа `text/html`, либо принимать любой ответ с сервера как текстовый?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Content-type приходит таким:
<code>
 application/json;charset=UTF-8
</code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как [утверждают доки ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload), форма ожидает `text/html` и с этим, видимо, ничего не поделать.
Но можно попробовать возвращать с сервера в методе обработчике бин, обернутый в [ResponseEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html):

```
TransactionResultMessage message;
// Тут все что надо
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "html", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
return new ResponseEntity<TransactionResultMessage>(message, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Ух ё! Наконец-то хоть один ответ! Уже два дня на этом застрял. СПАСИБО! Оказалось, что это функция отправки формы ждет ответа от сервера в формате <code>text/html</code>. А с другими, значит, срабатывает (например <code>Ext.Ajax.request()</code> ). Я определенно некачественно читаю документацию (т.е. практически на понимаю английский). Завтра попробую.  
<b>PS</b>. Я уж думал, что никто не откликнется на такую задачу.

Comment: Все хорошо сработало! Классная идея! Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: пожалуйста :)